# socket.io acknowledgement returns initial value instead of updated one (React + Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm creating a **namespace** with **socket.io** on **nodejs server**. When a user connects to the socket, I create a uuid that I use to store users in an assiociative array.

Then in **React**, I emit an event "getUsers" with a callback function to get all the connected users.

The callback returns the initial value of the array, so an empty one...
Here is my code:

**Nodejs server**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors:{
        origin: '*',
    }
});

let users = [];

const connections = io.of('/my_namespace');
connections.on('connection', async socket => {

    const userId = uuidv4();
    users[userId] = {
      data1: 'xxx',
      ...
    }

    socket.on('getUsers', (callback) => {
        console.log('users', users); // displays the array of all users, as it should
        callback(users); // returns an empty array...
    });
    
    ...
}
```

**React**

```
socket.emit('getUsers', (users) => {
    console.log(users); // displays an empty array
});
```

I tried adding data in the **socket.emit()** call, same result.
I changed the initialisation of **users**, like `let users = ["i'm a user array"]` and the console log in React displayed **["i'm a user array"]**
I also tried, on the server side :

```
socket.on('getUsers', (callback) => {
    console.log(users); // => displays the array of users, as it should
    callback([ ...users, "i'm a user"]);
}
```

and I got `["i'm a user"]` in the console on React...

So it seems that the callback gets only the initialized value of the **users** variable, but don't get the updated one...

What am I missing ?
Do I have to resort to emit the list of users instead of using a callback ?

**EDIT**

Even if I use a **socket.emit()** instead of the callback, I get the initial value, while the `console.log(users)` called just before the emit or callback displays all my users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `let users = [];` to `let users = {};` and it works.
I must miss some basic knowledge about associative arrays, because I don't understand why it won't send through functions...